# Changing the order of elements created using ::before and ::after in CSS

Tags: html, css, styled-components

I've tried to simplify my problem into the below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opactiy: 0;
}

.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

 .label:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -24px;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
  }

.label:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
   left: -24px;
   display: block;
   height: 40px;
   content: "";
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="checkbox"></input>
  <label class="label">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      Option 1
    </div>  
  </label>
</div>
```

In addition to this, I have the following CSS (in a StyledComponent) that adds a "check" to the checkbox when the user clicks on the hidden `input` in the `.input`:

```
  &[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label::after {
    background-image: url("${checkboxImage}");
    top: -2px;
    left: -29px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
```

This means it behaves as a checkbox should - however, I want to swap my elements around so that the checkbox sits to the right of the text instead of the left, to do this I have tried re-ordering the `input` so that it comes after the `label` but then the hidden input (which is handling the actual click behaviour is disjointed from the CSS checkbox? Can anyone point me in the direction of how I might resolve this?

Summary:
Using `:before` & `:after` to create a visual checkbox, but the logic for that checkbox is actually handled by `input` (which is hidden) - how can I move both the visual & hidden input to the right of the text?

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

```
.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 0;
  flex-grow: 1; /* ADDED THIS */
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1; /* ADDED THIS */
}
.label.reverse{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 200px;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 24px;
  margin-right: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.label.reverse > .label-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.label.reverse{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

 .label:before {
 position:absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
  }

.label:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   height: 20px;
   content: "";
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: 80%;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .label::after {
    background-image: url("https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/447/447147.png");
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input input1" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label" for="checkbox1">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      Option 1
    </div>  
  </label>
</div>


<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input input2" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label reverse" for="checkbox2">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
      Option 2
    </div>  
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - it really helped. One further question I have (which I should have outlined in the original question), but is it possible to display the checkbox to end of the wrapper (so it sits at the very right hand side)? I would usually use flex-end but obviously as the label is where the checkbox is coming from that isn't possible?

Comment: I didnt get your question. It is at the end of the wrapper and right of the text in option 2 checkbox. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Imagine if the `.wrapper` has a width of 200px, I'm asking how it would be possible to position the checkbox to the "right-end" of the wrapper? Have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Sure, I have added `flex: 1` in `.label` style and `flex-grow:1` in `.label-wrapper` style. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the left to right default position of elements?
If that's the case you can use text-align or float. Or even flexbox.
Also, put the text inside a span or something so you can control it.

If I have understood you correctly, there are many ways based on context like using absolute positioning, or put the label before input and close it. or something like this:

```js
<label class="">
    <span class="">text</span>
    <input class="" type="checkbox" name="order">        
</label>
```

Comment: Basically just trying to "swap" the checkbox and label around so that the checkbox (and the hidden input) sit to the right of the label.